# Search Bar Logic Error in Knockout Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have created Pagination table in knockout using SimpleGrid and Loaded data from a JSON Data. I Created a Search Bar to filter values from JSON Data and display the results in the pagination table.

I use jquery Filter method and Toggle method to search data from table. The Problem is search only works for current page(search only works in tbody) not retrieving data from remaining pages of Pagination simple Grid

Here is my jquery Code to search in Pagination Simple Grid

```
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {

                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

                $(".ko-grid tbody tr").filter(function() {

                        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value)>-1);
                });
            });
```

Search Works simply fine for the current page in Simple Grid. But i want the search to filter data from JSON and display the results in SimpleGrid Table.

Here is Sample Output that filter Data from Current Page 1

[Image that Filter Search Result From Current Page Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLKoR.jpg)

But I want the Search Results to Load from All pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply search logic to whole grid - you need to filter out your original array of items, which you're providing to grid as a source.
So, you will need to create an additional computed which will depend on search value and your original array and replace the source of datagrid from your original items to filtered:

```
   this.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!this.searchText()) {
            return this.originalItems();
        }

        var searchTextLowered = this.searchText().toLowerCase();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.originalItems(), function (item) {
            return item.text().indexOf(searchTextLowered) === 0;
        });
    }, this);
```

Then on keyUp you can update your observable (or can rewrite this to bind search value directly with knockout) :

```
        var ctx = this;
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {

            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            ctx.searchText(value);
        });
```